# PostgreSQL prevent row with null password when authentication type name is password

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, sequelize.js, constraints

I have 2 tables in PostgreSQL

**authentication_type**

| id | name | created_at | updated_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| c1cc0489-4740-4dca-9d63-14e4c26093ad | password | ... | ... |

**accounts**

| id | email | password | authentication_type_id | created_at | updated_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ... | abc@example.com |  | (foreign key to the other table) | ... | ... |

I would like to insert the row under the condition that

- When authentication type name is password, the value of the password column cannot be null

**What I have tried?**

```
CHECK CONSTRAINT (
  authentication_type_id='c1cc0489-4740-4dca-9d63-14e4c26093ad'
  AND
  password IS NOT NULL
)
```

but this is not working. I am not sure how to write an if else condition here

**Questions**

- Is it possible to do this with a CHECK CONSTRAINT or do I need a before insert trigger? What is the difference between both?

I am using sequelize to do this if that helps

Comment: Whenever you use an `AND` inside your `CHECK` you are checking two separate conditions and should consider making it two separate CHECKs. In this case this is not what you want, so the `AND` is wrong. See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got the boolean logic wrong. You want one (or both) of the following:

- the type_id is not the "password-id"
- the password is not empty

```
CHECK CONSTRAINT (
    authentication_type_id != 'c1cc0489-4740-4dca-9d63-14e4c26093ad'
    OR
    password IS NOT NULL
)
```